# Why is no Rakshas having supernatural powers present in Kaliyuga?

Tags: rakshasa

There is no Rakshas having supernatural powers seen in Kaliyuga , Why ?

Comment: How do you know they don't? Have you seen any rakshasas?

Comment: vibhesna is still alive he is rakshana but sattvika qulities  according to scripture.. Mayaassur who build palace for pandavas indraprastha is still there. they are all living disguise in kaliyuga.. because with single bullet one can kill this raksahas and asura now.. so even if they are alive they wont show or exihibit there qualities.. like what they have done in dwapara or kreta yuga.. but i believe they invisible in human form  now.. delhi serial killing of children.. all the missing cases if thoroghly investiageated will be asura or rakshasa..